# Xamarin Forms refer to controls inside the ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

How can I refer the controls inside the `ViewCell` of a `ListView`:

```
    <ListView x:Name="classesListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
              HasUnevenRows="True" 
              HeightRequest="200" 
              ItemSelected="ListView_OnSelection">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell Height="50">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Switch x:Name="chooseItem" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding ClassName}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

How can I refer to the `Switch` in the code behind(in the `ListView_OnSelection` method)

Thanks

Comment: It's better to use binding. Tell me, please, what do you want to handle in `Switch`?

Comment: I need to add the Label text to an array if the switch is toggled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add new property to model and the use binding to see if `Switch` `IsToggled`:

```
<Switch x:Name="chooseItem" 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        IsToggled="{Binding IsSelectedForBeingAddedToArray, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try it

Comment: Sir, i defined this property on my view model can you help me on the nexst step? private bool _isSelectedForBeingAddedToArray;
        public bool IsSelectedForBeingAddedToArray {
            get
            {
                return _isSelectedForBeingAddedToArray;
            }
            set
            {
                _isSelectedForBeingAddedToArray = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: Not in view model, in model, that you are binded to list item

Comment: It's not working, if it's two way mode the switch should be toggled when I tap the listview cell, is it wrong? The code: void ListView_OnSelection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) {
            var selectedItem = e.SelectedItem as Class;
            selectedItem.IsSelectedForBeingAddedToArray = !selectedItem.IsSelectedForBeingAddedToArray;
            
        }

Comment: `if(selectedItem.IsSelectedForBeingAddedToArray)` - then add this item to array

Comment: Thanks a lot it work to add item to the array but can't the switch be toggled when I tap the cell?

Comment: Even if you tap exactly on the `Switch`?

Comment: I couldn't refer the selected item when the switch is toggled

Comment: You could create [behavior](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/behaviors/) for `Switch` and listen for `Toggled` event.